# How to get UDID for Apple Watch

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

Is there any way to extract UDID for Apple Watch?
I have clicked on icon button inside watch but did not find anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Connect the paired iPhone to your computer and open Xcode. Open Window > Devices and click on your iPhone. The paired Watch's information will be available in the same view, including UDID.

Comment: HI, information u posted is very help full thanks, plz let me know solution for this. I need to send a watch kit application to another tester, using Ad-Hoc deployment.
The tester is not an engineer, and he doesn't have xcode. How can I get his Apple Watch UDID ???

I need to add his Apple Watch UDID to the ad-hoc distribution profile...